# Printing character pointer versus printing character by dereferencing

Tags: c++

```
char c = 'a';

char* p = &c;

cout << p << endl;

cout << *p << endl;
```

This is a code written in C++ language.

Why in the first cout statement the program tries to print until it finds a null character and in the second statement it just prints a single character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, pointers to `char` are often considered a "C string" by convention -- which is a null-terminated string of `char`s. This is an expected convention in much of the C++ standard library -- and this holds true in `std::ostream` as well.

In particular, in your two calls:

1. The pointer `p` will call `std::ostream`'s [`operator<<(const char*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overload -- which prints it as a null-terminated character string, and
2. The `char` `*p` will call `std::ostream`'s [`operator<<(char)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overload for characters, which prints the singular character

---

**Note:** If you want to print the *address* of the pointer itself, you will want to call the [`operator<<(const void*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload -- which requires an explicit cast to `void*`:

```cpp
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << std::endl;
```

This operator is not discovered automatically since the language sees that `operator<<(const char*)` does not require any type conversions to take place for `p`.

Comment: But `p` isn't a `const char*`, it's a `char*`, so why is that overload better? I guess it doesn't have any overloads that accept pointer-to-non-`const` and the `const void*` member is a less close match than the `const char*` free function?

Comment: @NathanPierson `const` declaration in function argument concerns only function itself, i.e. function can't modify contents of this pointer, but doesn't mean that you can't pass non-const pointer.

Comment: @NathanPierson The short/simplified answer: During overload resolution, if an exact match is not discovered (in this case `char*`), the compiler can select an overload if it is more constrained in terms of CV qualifiers for pointer/reference arguments -- in this case `const char*` is selected.

Answer (score -1):

It's specific thing of C and C++. Pointer of char means string with zero symbol at end.

Comment: Both of these statements are false.

Comment: _"Pointer of char means string with zero symbol at end"_ -- this is, at most, a common _convention_ -- but this isn't universally true. Fundamentally a pointer to `char` is just a pointer to a `char` sequence of `0` or greater `char`s -- but there is nothing in the language that expects it to be null-terminated; that's only by convention. There are plenty of cases where `char` pointers won't be null terminated, such as for stack buffers,  `std::string_view` (or any equivalent), etc.